# i want to stop service that is requare admin privileges

Tags: services, non-admin

I want to stop some service in a non-admin account, but it requires admin rights, and I can't also open the cmd in admin mode because it needs the user name and password for admin, but I don't know them, so how can I stop a service that requires admin rights?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why don’t you just whomever has Administrator permissions to perform this task for you?

Answer (score 1):

In a modern (Win 10 and above), if you are not the Administrator, you cannot stop a service requiring Admin rights.

Not possible, so get someone in your shop with admin rights to do this for you.